# Custom flat list items in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a flatlist with list items. I managed to build one using one of the samples from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html.

I am trying to extend this by creating something more complicated but I am stuck. I am trying to create a flatlist with list items like below. Ofcourse I can achive this by using one of those react native libraries but I am trying to avoid using libraries instead I want to construct a flatlist component with multiple renders because this approach would give me more control of the component. Would appreciate any help with this.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to split your date before adding it to the flatlist? You can also create the views before you put an array into the list. Than you just return the item itself in the renderItem function.

Comment: You can use [`numColumns`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns)

Comment: Should I build a jsx for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve it is to have a Row component and based on props you determine how to render it. Example:

```
class Row extends React.PureComponent {

   render(){
      const { item } = this.props
      if(item.break){
         return <Text>Break</Text>
      }
      return (
         <View><Text>Normal item goes here</Text></View>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. When I create a sharable flatlist component like 
export default function FlatList ({
  listData
}:{
  listData: string
}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          style={Styles.container}
          data={listData}
          renderItem={renderRow}
        />
    </View>    
  )
}

renderRow will contain the logic of constructing JSX but with this I get an error saying "maximum call stack size exceeded". Is it because I cannot pass a json string as a parameter to my custom component?

Comment: You shouldn’t call your functional component FlatList because when you use the original FlatList in jsx it takes your custom function instead causing a recursion. Change it to just List

Comment: I dont believe we have a List in react native. Did you mean ListView?

Comment: It's an arbitrary name you give to your component, you can call it RigorousImplementation if you wish